# Godot2D How can i make the enemy's attack collision work

Tags: 2d, sprite, collision, godot

[image]

I'm making a player's death system, but when the enemy collide with the player, nothing happens, well... it print in log how many life's left but its just it, i have created the area 2D group (Hurtbox) and (power(The enemy's area group)), colissionshape and everything else

Comment: So to be clear. The life is printed in the console? If yes, your collision seems to work fine, because you wouldn't have that log otherwise (given by the code you posted). Then I would check your Animationplayer.

Answer (score 1):

Play the animation and yield:

```
    if life == 0:
        $Spritezada.play("Dead")
        yield($Spritezada, "animation_finished")
        print("died")
        queue_free()
```

The above code will play the animation, then halt the execution. When the animation player raises the signal `animation_finished` it will resume, print `"died"` and set the current node for removal (`queue_free`).

---

By the way, the `animation_finished` signal passes a text parameter. If you do not want to use `yield` as suggested above, write your code like so:

```
func _on_Spritezada_animation_finished(anim_name: String):
    if anim_name == "Dead":
        queue_free()
```

I believe Godot should be telling you about that missing parameter. If you don't see a message about that, double check you connected the correct signal.